# Error: Index was out of range after enabling JIRA extension (Issue Tracker)

Tags: jira, plasticscm

I wanted to try the JIRA extension for Plastic SCM. So I've added all information in Preferences > Issue Tracker, tested connection successful. Seemed to work...

But I couldn't see anything in Branch Explorer > Options > "Atlassin JIRA". So I've turned it off again. But now I'm getting the error `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index`. And I can't open any Branch Explorer anymore.

The log files doesn't really help me solving this issue.

Is there a preferences file I could delete? What can I do?

I'm using Plastic SCM 7.0.16.2421.

Comment: Could you send your client log to support@codicesoftware.com? It seems to be a problem with some client-side configuration. I would manually remove the issue trackers configuration folder: "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\plastic4\issuetrackers" and then restart the GUI.

Comment: Sent you the logs. But I already did an update to 8.0. Because it was urgent. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated to Plastic SCM 8.0 and the error was gone.